# Ubuntu Pro 20.04 - Canonical Livepatch - apt-check - eats all memory and Server unresponsive intermittently - until a reboot

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Ubuntu Pro 20.04 and Canonical Livepatch apt-check eat all memory and hang the server until we reboot it.

t3.nano 512 MB RAM in use, and multiple instances have the same issue.

We need a solution to resolve this issue and keep our host alive. There should be a way to reduce memory use for apt-check.

Here are some logs:

kern.log:Nov -- -- -- -- 2 servername kernel: [5430239.701186] systemd-journal invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=-250

kern.log:Nov -- -- -- --  servername kernel: [5430239.701463] Out of memory: Killed process 509179 (apt-check) total-vm:158336kB, anon-rss:83104kB, file-rss:4204kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:348kB oom_score_adj

Answer (score 1):

Get more memory. `apt` is killed when consuming 158MB. Increase the memory, or stop the other services you're running that's consuming memory. 512MB is evidently not enough to run your service and perform updates.

The [suggested amounts](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation) is 1GB:

> The recommended system requirements are:
>
> - CPU: 1 gigahertz or better
> - RAM: 1 gigabyte or more
> - Disk: a minimum of 2.5 gigabytes

---

512MB is *tiny* today. It's to be expected that modern general purpose Linux distros simply doesn't work well with such limited memory at their disposal; optimizing for more memory allows them to perform better and have more features in the *vast* majority of cases.

For such tiny instances I would suggest going with

- Treating the VM's as containers and destroy and recreate, rather than upgrade
- Containerizing using e.g. Docker
- Sticking with a tiny distro optimized for such systems, such as Alpine